# Join To Max Date /w a Max Record

Tags: sql, join, max

I figured out one way to do so but it is so horribly slow and has far too many sub queries which make it run like it's going through mud since there can be hundreds of thousands of records. Basically, I need the maximum date for each PendingId up to 3 times. Usually it may only have 1 pendingId which results in null for 2 and 3 which is intended.  This is what I have right now that is super slow:

```
SELECT  a.*
        ,c.ActivityDte AS Date1
        ,d.ActivityDte AS Date2
        ,e.ActivityDte AS Date3
FROM Tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN Tbl2 c
    ON a.IdNbr = c.IdNbr
    AND c.ActivityDte = (SELECT MAX(ActivityDte) AS MaxActivityDte
                        FROM Tbl2
                        WHERE IdNbr = a.IdNbr
                        AND PendingId = (SELECT MAX(PendingId) 
                                        FROM Tbl2
                                        WHERE IdNbr = a.IdNbr)
                        )
LEFT JOIN Tbl2 d
    ON a.IdNbr = d.IdNbr
    AND d.ActivityDte = (SELECT MAX(ActivityDte) AS MaxActivityDte
                        FROM Tbl2
                        WHERE IdNbr = a.IdNbr
                        AND PendingId = (SELECT MAX(PendingId) - 1
                                        FROM Tbl2
                                        WHERE IdNbr = a.IdNbr)
                        )
LEFT JOIN Tbl2 e
    ON a.IdNbr = e.IdNbr
    AND e.ActivityDte = (SELECT MAX(ActivityDte) AS MaxActivityDte
                        FROM Tbl2
                        WHERE IdNbr = a.IdNbr
                        AND PendingId = (SELECT MAX(PendingId) -2
                                        FROM Tbl2
                                        WHERE IdNbr = a.IdNbr)
```

Comment: what is your database?

Comment: Show us some example data and expected output to better understand the problem.